# Avoid handling if error has response in Vue with Axios in every request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling, vuejs2, axios

I use the axios interceptors to handle some errors, specially the errors without response. And in some parts of my project, I use the message contained in the error.response.data for validations and showing a messaged stored in the backend. But this interceptor is not preventing me from having to check if the error has a response.

My interceptor:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
      ...
    },
    function (error) {
      if (!error.response) {
        ...
        return Promise.reject(new Error(error.message))
      }
```

An example of a request that depends on having the error.response:

```
this.$store.dispatch('updateField', { [this.fieldKey]: this.value ? this.value : null }).catch((error) => {
        this.validateField(error.response.data)
      })
```

But I'd have to put the validateField call inside an `if(eror.response)` to avoid an error in the console, and spread this if all over my code?

Answer (score 0):

`response` can be treated as optional, because it actually is:

```
this.validateField(error.response?.data)
```

Or normalized error that contains needed properties and doesn't rely on the structure of Axios error can be created in an interceptor:

```
function (rawError) {
  const error = new Error(error.response?.data?.myError || error.message);
  error.data = error.response?.data || null;
  error.headers = error.response?.headers || null;
  error.status = error.response?.status || 0;
  return Promise.reject(error);
}
```